# LookupEdit devexpress combo box

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a lookupedit combo box using dev express tools.  I want to somehow loop through and grab each value in the combox box.  So If i have 5 values, I want to be able to iterate over all and grab the value.

I tried to assign the bindingsource to a datatable but i got unable to cast object of type source to datatable.

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = CType(BindingSourceWell.DataSource, DataTable)
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

WinForms data sources should implement at least the IList interface. So, you can cast the LookUpEdit data source to IList to get a number of rows:

```
IList list = lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource as IList;
int count = list.Count;
```

So, you can use *count* as a parameter in your for loop to traverse through all rows.

Then, you can get a row cell value by using the [RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.GetDataSourceValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEdit_GetDataSourceValuetopic%28dn-9mQ%29) method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var value = lookUpEdit1.Properties.GetDataSourceValue('your field name', i);
}
```